# Data Structure for a recursive function with two parameters one of which is Large the other small

Tags: c, data-structures

Mathematician here looking for a bit of help. (If you ever need math help I'll try to reciprocate on math.stackexchange!) Sorry if this is a dup. Couldn't find it myself.

Here's the thing. I write a lot of code (mostly in C) that is extremely slow and I know it could be sped up considerably but I'm not sure what data structure to use. I went to school 20 years ago and unfortunately never got to take a computer science course. I have watched a lot of open-course videos on data structures but I'm still a bit fuddled never taking an actual class.

Mostly my functions just take integers to integers. I almost always use 64-bit numbers and I have three use cases that I'm interested in. I use the word small to mean no more than a million or two in quantity.

Case 1: Small numbers as input. Outputs are arbitrary.

Case 2: Any 64-bit values as input, but only a small number of them. Outputs are arbitrary.

Case 3: Two parameter functions with one parameter that's small in value (say less than two million), and the other parameter is Large but with only a small number of possible inputs. Outputs are arbitrary.

For Case 1, I just make an array to cache the values. Easy and fast.
For Case 2, I think I should be using a hash. I haven't yet done this but I *think* I could figure it out if I took the time.
Case 3 is the one I'd like help with and I'm not even sure what I need.

For a specific example take a function F(n,p) that takes large inputs n for the first parameter and a prime p for the second. The prime is at most the square root of n. so even if n is about 10^12, the primes are only up to about a million. Suppose this function is recursive or otherwise difficult to calculate (expensive) and will be called over and over with the same inputs. What might be a good data structure to use to easily create and retrieve the possible values of F(n,p) so that I don't have to recalculate it every time? Total number of possible inputs should be 10 or 20 million at most.

Help please! and Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps radix tree by splitting input into bytes

Comment: OK. Never heard of a radix tree, I will read up on it. Thank you!

Comment: `Total number of possible inputs should be 10 or 20 million at most.` -->> hashfunction() -->> hashtable.

Comment: The way you've asked this question makes memoization the only answer.  It's likely, however, that there are better answers for most specific instances of your problem, often involving a restructuring of the algorithm that's calling these functions.

Comment: @MattTimmermans. Yes that's true. Sometimes you can find a way to calculate things in order so that you don't really need to memoize but in my experience that is almost always not a natural way to solve the problem. So I was just looking for some tips on how to memoize a two parameter function.

Comment: @wildplasser. I will try to make that work, but I'm still unclear if that will work for two or more parameters.

Comment: If the cartesian product of the parameter domains is small enough, then you just combine them into one value and memoize with that as your key.  Otherwise, you try to find a subproblem with a smaller domain that makes the outer function easier to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) I presume. Trying to answer without a concrete exemple...

If you have to retrieve values from a small range (the 2nd parameter), say from 0 to 10^6, and that needs to be upper fast, and... you have enough memory, you could simply declare an array of `int` (`long`...), which basically stores the output values from all input.

To make things simple, let say the value `0` means  there is no-value set

```
long *small = calloc(MAX, sizeof(*small)); // Calloc intializes to 0
```

then in a function that gives the value for a small range

```
if (small[ input ]) return small[ input ];
....calculate
small[ input ] = value;
```

**+/-**

- `+` Very fast
- `-` Memory consumption takes the whole range, `[ 0, MAX-1 ]`.

If you need to store arbitrary input, use the many libraries available (there are so many). Use a `Set` structure, that tells if the items exists or no.

```
if (set.exists( input )) return set.get( input );
....calculate
set.set( input, value );
```

**+/-**

- `+` less memory usage
- `+` still fast (said to be O(1))
- `-` but, not as fast as a mere array

Add to this the hashed set (...), which are faster, as in terms of probabilities, values (hashes) are better distributed.

**+/-**

- `+` less memory usage than array
- `+` faster than a simple Set
- `-` but, not as fast as a mere array
- `-` use more memory than a simple Set

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Yes I'm talking about memoizing a function. I'll I've ever really used are arrays. Would the set or hashed set work for multiple inputs? or would I have to convert the two inputs into a string or something? I guess I'm not sure how that would work.